# How to add padding to a robot using ROS2/MoveIt2?

Tags: ros2, moveit, path-planning, collision

I am trying to find a way to add padding to the robot to avoid unwanted collisions caused by low control precision. Optimally I could either set a uniform padding of e.g. 5 cm or - even better - specific padding values for each link of the robot.

During my research I found [this old post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/80802) valid for ROS/MoveIt that proposes to set a parameter `default_robot_padding: 0.05`. Here is the old post:

Unfortunately I can't get this working with ROS2/MoveIt2. So here are my questions:

- Is it the right approach at all to set a padding parameter to avoid unwanted collisions due to low precision?
- How and where can I set a padding parameter?
- Would it be possible to add parameters close to the robot definition, e.g. directly in the URDF?
- Could it be set vor individual joints differently?

My setup is:

- ROS2 Iron
- MoveIt2 (Main branch, there is no iron currently)
- Ubuntu 22.04

Any help or direction in which I can have a look would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matching your set of four questions:

- Yes, default_robot_padding is probably the best (only?) MoveIt2 parameter to currently deal with poor control tolerances.
- I believe you can add this to the joint_limits.yaml that was generated for your robot via the moveit_setup_assistant (see below for more details on why this is the correct file).
- Technically, you could encode similar information in the URDF - but it would likely be challenging to get correct - you'd have to adjust the scale (and possibly also the origin) of each collision mesh/geometry in your URDF. Note that scaling the meshes up is likely not exactly the same as applying padding around them.
- MoveIt2 wouldn't be able inflate the collision mesh/geometry on a per-joint value (the URDF approach would be capable) - but I want to specifically clarify here: this is really a parameter of the collision mesh/geometry, not the joint itself. What you are doing is inflating the size of the mesh/geometry - that is quite a bit different than modeling the actual ambiguity of where the robot geometry is based on the control error - I am not aware of any available collision checker which supports such.

With regards to where to put the parameters, unfortunately, the launch files generated in MoveIt2 are a bit convoluted - my rational here is that the full parameter name is "[robot_description_planning.default_robot_padding](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/47d92ef973680aea1badd6cc6080598f040a89f4/moveit_ros/planning/planning_scene_monitor/src/planning_scene_monitor.cpp#L1616)". joint_limits.yaml includes the "default_velocity_scaling_factor" parameter [which is also in the robot_description_planning namespace](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/47d92ef973680aea1badd6cc6080598f040a89f4/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L153) - therefore, the entire contents of the joint_limits.yaml should be loaded into the proper namespace.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @mike ! It immediately worked for a single robot configuration by just adding the 'default_robot_padding' parameter in the joint_limits.yaml. Note: The value of type double is specified in meters (example: 0.05 equals 5 cm padding). 

It did not work for a dual arm configuration out of the box thought. The reason was how the robot_description_parameters where puzzled together from the two robot entities. The code only took care of including values inside the 'joint_limits' key in the joint_limits.yaml and ignored the manually added 'default_robot_padding'.

Comment: Mike, do you have any idea of how one could implement padding between 2 robot arms, e.g. to avoid real-world collisions when using moveit2 for planning trajectorys for dual arm configurations? I am kind of stuck here.

Comment: Internally, MoveIt has the notion of "robot" and "environment" for collision checking. I'm not entirely sure how robot-robot is done (I would expect it is similar to how self-collision checking is done - but then I'm not entirely sure if paddling is used in that case).