# How to avoid collision of 2 robot arms in real world (padding between robots)? ROS2/Moveit2

Tags: ros2, moveit, path-planning, collision

I recently [submitted a question regarding how to apply padding to a robot arm in general using ROS2/MoveIt2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/103825/how-to-add-padding-to-a-robot-using-ros2-moveit2) and learned that one can define a 'default_robot_padding' parameter within the 'robot_description_planning' namespace. This works great for avoiding unwanted collisions between a robot arm and collision objects in real world scenarios. It is also usable to avoid collision of a dual arm robot (each robot arm) with it's environment / other collision objects placed in the planning scene.

But how can I add padding between two robot arms to avoid unwanted collisions of the arms itself in dual arm robot configurations (real world, where non-ideal mounting poses of robots meet manufacturing and joint control tolerances)?

Besides the straight-forward approach of adding padding, I would also be super interested to learn if there are alternative approaches to mitigate the risk of collisions in multi robot arm real-world settings.